# createPattern(this.image, 'repeat') returns null when image is locally saved

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

When I locally save the image http://www.tigrisgames.com/crate.png and run the program using that I do not get the repeating pattern as I get with the code below. Only 1 crate is shown stretched. I am thinking this has something to do with image not being loaded but I am unable to fix it. Any feedback would be appreciated.

```js
var Context = {
    canvas: null,
    context: null,
    create: function(canvas_tag_id){
        this.canvas = document.getElementById(canvas_tag_id);
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
        return this.context;
    }
}

var Sprite = function(filename, is_pattern){
    this.image = null;
    this.pattern = null;
    this.TO_RADIANS = Math.PI/180;
    if(filename != null && filename != "" && filename !=undefined ){
        this.image=  new Image();
        this.image.src = filename;
        if(is_pattern){
            
            this.pattern = Context.context.createPattern(this.image, 'repeat');
            console.log(this.pattern);

        }
    }else{
        console.log('Unable to load sprite');
    }

    this.draw = function(x,y,w,h){
        if(this.pattern != null){
            Context.context.fillStyle = this.pattern;
            Context.context.fillRect(x,y,w,h);
            
        }else{
            if(w == undefined || h == undefined){
                Context.context.drawImage(this.image, x,y, 
                                            this.image.width, 
                                            this.image.height);
            }else{
                //stretched
                Context.context.drawImage(this.image, x,y, w, h);
            }
        }
    }
}


$(document).ready(function(){
    
    Context.create('canvas');
    

    var wall = "http://www.tigrisgames.com/wall.png";
    var crate = 'http://www.tigrisgames.com/crate.png'; // 'crate.png' after saving locally in same folder


    var image = new Sprite(wall, false);
    var image2 = new Sprite(crate, false);
    var pattern = new Sprite(crate, true);
    var angle = 0;

    setInterval(function(){
        Context.context.fillStyle = "#000";
        Context.context.fillRect(0,0 , canvas.width, canvas.height);
        image.draw(0,0, undefined, 64);
        image.draw(0, 74, 256, 32);
        pattern.draw(160,160, 256, 180);

    }, 25);


});
```

```html
<canvas id = "canvas" width = "640" height = "480" style="border:1px solid gray"></canvas>


<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"   integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script  src="commands.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were several issues to fix:

- Use `onload` when using a image with the canvas-context, because `createPattern` will not work properly when it does not know the dimensions of the image without using `onload`.
- I‘ve inserted code to handle strech/unstrech image-display so have a look at the commented code.
- Use `window.requestAnimationFrame` because the animation stops when switching to another tab, more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29431333)
- Define this draw as `prototype`-function then you have got the advantage that draw is only created once not several times when a new instance is created
- Use a varibale like `instance` to make it clear at what context a property/method is called and its more failsafe in comparison with `this`
- I've made some comments in the code as well

```js
var Context = {
    canvas: null,
    context: null,
    create: function(canvas_tag_id){
        this.canvas = document.getElementById(canvas_tag_id);
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
        return this.context;
    }
}

var Sprite = function(filename, is_pattern, streched){
    var instance = this;
    instance.image = null;
    instance.pattern = null;
    instance.streched = streched; // do you want to streche a image or not
    instance.TO_RADIANS = Math.PI/180;
    if(filename != null && filename != "" && filename !=undefined ){
        instance.image =  new Image();
        // always use onload before using the image with the canvas-context
        instance.image.onload = function(){
          
          // remember w/h ration for unstreched display
          instance.ration = instance.image.width/instance.image.height;
          
          if(is_pattern){
            
            // createPattern did not know the dimensions of the image without onload 
            instance.pattern = Context.context.createPattern(instance.image, 'repeat');

          }
        };
        instance.image.src = filename;
    }else{
        console.log('Unable to load sprite');
    }

}

// this draw function is only created once not several times when a new instance is created
Sprite.prototype.draw = function(x,y,w,h){
        var instance = this;
        if(instance.pattern != null){
            Context.context.fillStyle = instance.pattern;
            Context.context.fillRect(x,y,w,h);
            
        }else{
            if(w == undefined || h == undefined){
                Context.context.drawImage(instance.image,x,y, 
                                            instance.image.width, 
                                            instance.image.height);
            }else{
                //stretched
                // you can now control whether to strech or not by using the thir constructor-param
                Context.context.drawImage(instance.image, x,y, w, instance.streched ? h : w*instance.ration);
            }
        }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    
    Context.create('canvas');
    

    var wall = "http://www.tigrisgames.com/wall.png";
    var crate = 'http://www.tigrisgames.com/crate.png'; // 'crate.png' after saving locally in same folder


    var image = new Sprite(wall, false, true);
    var image2 = new Sprite(wall, false, false); // image 2 is displayed unstreched because of third param
    var pattern = new Sprite(crate, true);
    var angle = 0;

    // better use this instead of setInterval
    var drawEverything = function(){
    
        Context.context.fillStyle = "#000";
        Context.context.fillRect(0,0 , canvas.width, canvas.height);
        image.draw(0,0, undefined, 64);
        // did you not want to use image2 instead? then the wall in the middle is displayed unstreched
        //image2.draw(0, 74, 256, 32);
        image.draw(0, 74, 256, 32);
        pattern.draw(160,160, 256, 180);
        
        setTimeout(function(){
          window.requestAnimationFrame(drawEverything);
        },25);
        
    };
    
    window.requestAnimationFrame(drawEverything);


});

// better use this instead of setInterval
window.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame
    || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame
    || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame
    || window.msRequestAnimationFrame
    || function(f){return setTimeout(f, 1000/60)}
```

```html
<canvas id = "canvas" width = "640" height = "480" style="border:1px solid gray"></canvas>


<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"   integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script  src="commands.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry but that link to the RAF explanation is about the worst I have read in some time. The author does not have the slightest clue why you should use RAF or what RAF acctualy does. The most important aspect of RAF is that content changes made during the callback are held and only presented (compositied) to display RAM during the next Vertical refresh cycle, rather than emidiatly as with any other javascript functions. You should find a better link or remove it as it is wowfull.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, the link was replaced with a better one. Cheers :)